# May I know why the two formula is equivalent?

Tags: integers

[image]

This is  a lemma 6 in published article called The Number of Prime Factors on Average in Certain Integer Sequences, page8. i have some trouble expounding or looking for the in between equation, before its came up to the second formula. Im not quite familiar with the notations that they using since it wasn't defined properly

example link, where u can view the article, retrieved from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358229491_The_Number_of_Prime_Factors_on_Average_in_Certain_Integer_Sequences

Comment: Can you explain some of the notation here? For example what is $\mu$? The Mobius function? Can you point us to the article?

Comment: i didnt quite comprehend as to how they used the notation, might viewing the article will help you

Comment: @jay taylor, is it possible to use the mobius function into this one?